# Auto-increment value from mysql Insert query

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(!class_exists('MySql'))
{ include('MySql.php'); }
  $sql=new MySql();
  $sql->connect();
  $sqlCommand="insert into `freecomputermarket`.`members`
 (`UserName`,`Password`,`Email`,`BirthDate`,`RegisterationDate`,`ActivationCode`,
 `ActivationLink`,`IsActive`,`Gender`)
 values('$this->_userName','$this->_password','$this->_email','$this->_birthDate',
 '$this->_registerationDate','$this->_activationCode','$this->_activationLink',
 '$this->_isActive','$this->_gender')";
  $sql->query($sqlCommand);
```

how i can get the Auto-increment ID inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hidden the implementation details of your `MySql` class very well.

- In case you are using **PDO**, you will want to have a look at [LastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)
- In case you are using **mysqli**, look at [mysql_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php);
- In case you are using **mysql**: switch to PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql->query($sqlCommand);
$id = lastInsertId();
```

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: is this function raise an error if the command is select for example?
or return null?

Comment: You would have to try/catch any exceptions, see examples in my previous link (in the comments).